# Handle and re-raise exceptions thrown by python logging module

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, logging, handler

### Question

How do I write a custom handler for a python `logging` logger that will catch an `IOError` caused by a sudden inability to write logging information to file and re-raise the error as a different type?

### Further information

I'm reading and converting a large repository of raw data and it's important for me to record the process (python `logging` module). If logging fails because of some error, e.g. `IOError`, I would like the application to gracefully exit. Over the weekend, the network location where I write my log files crashed and the conversion process gamely continued.

There can be an `IOError` thrown by other components in my code (e.g. a raw file to convert for a given hour is not present indicating that the detector was down for that given period in time) that are not important and can be ignored. I catch these errors and continue with the next hour of data.

If the logger threw a different, custom exception I could handle it separately. Something like (disclaimer: this doesn't work):

```python
class WarningFileHandler(logging.FileHandler):
    """File handler for only writing WARNING log information to disk"""

    def __init__(self,filename,mode='a',encoding=None,delay=False):
        logging.FileHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding, delay)

    def emit(self, record):
        # Filter out all record objects that are not at the logging.WARNING level.
        if not record.levelno == logging.WARNING:
            return
        try:
            logging.FileHandler.emit(self, record)
        except IOError as e:
            # The logger cannot write successfully to disk (e.g. a network
            # resource becomes unavailable).
            raise LoggerIOError("[ERROR NO {0}: {1}]. Logger write "
                    "failure.".format(e.errno,e.strerror))
```

`LoggerIOError` is a simple, custom exception.

```python
class LoggerIOError(Exception):
    """Logger IOError"""
    pass
```

Can anyone provide some help or advice? I don't have much experience with the `logging` module and so I may be overlooking something simple.

`logging.raiseExceptions` should be its default value of `True`.

#### Details

OS/Python details:

- Windows 7
- Python 2.7

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? I have a similar conundrum, writing logs to an SMB share that is likely to be unavailable at _some point_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exceptions are handled by the `handleError` method of a handler, documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.handleError). Subclass a relevant handler to implement custom error processing. The `handleError` method is called from the exception clause, so `sys.exc_info()` should return the current exception.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The question has been edited to reflect your solution.